# is there any way to permanently turn off overwrite on notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, overwrite

I've looked in a lot of places but haven't found it. is it impossible, or are there just no guides for it?
I've found a tutorial on it for word but not notepad++.

Comment: What do you mean permanently? Don't press insert or hit the toggle and it will remain in insert mode?

Answer (score 4):

Press the "`Ins`" (insert) on your keyboard, that should change to `add` again instead of `overwrite`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a simple answer!

Under the *Settings* menu, click *Shortcut Mapper*.
In Shortcut Mapper, navigate to the tab called *Scintilla commands*.
Use the 'Filter' textbox near the bottom to search "*overtype*" and locate the shortcut named ***SCI_EDITTOGGLEOVERTYPE***. Click on that, choose **Modify**, then use the drop-down to **change the input key from "INS" to "None"**, and then select **Apply**.

From now on, the insert key will not toggle overtype mode.